# BlackBerry Push Notifications , OS < 7.X

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, push

I am working on developing a BB OS<7.X application, that implements push notifications. I finally ended up with some working code that is able to receive push.

However, the push notifications *DONT* work the first time i deploy the application on the phone. If i try to send a push on the device, after i just deployed it, when i send the push from my server, i can see on the right up corner of my device a little arrow loading , but no push message is displayed on the screen.

If i restart the device, the push notifications work properly!! Now whenever i send a push, i see the little arrow again on up right screen and the push message displayed corrected.

The code looks like this(the parts i consider important):

***MyApp.java***

```java
   public class MyApp extends UiApplication
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            //every time we start the application we register to BIS for push
            if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("BlackBerryCity")) {
                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!I am inside if");
                //registering for push
                push_main.registerBpas();
                MyApp app = new MyApp();
                app.enterEventDispatcher();
            }

            //every time we restart the phone , we call this background process that is responsible for listening for push
            else {
                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!I am inside else");
                //should put the background classes for listening to pushed msgs :D
                BackgroundApplication backApp=new BackgroundApplication();
                backApp.setupBackgroundApplication(); 
                backApp.enterEventDispatcher();                 
            }                               
        }

        public MyApp()
        {
            pushScreen(new MyAppScreen());
        }
    }

    class MyAppScreen extends MainScreen
    {
        public MyAppScreen()
        {             
             //some stuff here..
        }
     }
```

**push_main.java**

```java
public class push_main {

/**
 * Entry point for this application
 * @param args Command line arguments (not used)
 */

private static final String REGISTER_SUCCESSFUL = "rc=200";
private static final String DEREGISTER_SUCCESSFUL = REGISTER_SUCCESSFUL;
private static final String USER_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED = "rc=10003";
private static final String ALREADY_UNSUSCRIBED_BY_USER = "rc=10004";
private static final String ALREADY_UNSUSCRIBED_BY_PROVIDER = "rc=10005";

private static final String PUSH_PORT = ""+"33387";  //push port
private static final String BPAS_URL = "http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com";
private static final String APP_ID = ""+ "3592-M4587f9s9k836r930kO2395i32i66y10a34";   // add application id

private static String URL = "http://:"+ "33397"; //   add your push port.
private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 256;                

public static ListeningThread _listeningThread;
public static StreamConnectionNotifier _notify;

private static final long ID = 0x954a603c0dee81e0L;


public push_main() {    

        if(_listeningThread==null)
        {
            System.out.println("msg on listening thread 1");        
            _listeningThread = new ListeningThread();
            System.out.println("msg on listening thread 2");
            _listeningThread.start();
            System.out.println("msg on listhning thread 3 ");       
        }         
}

public static class ListeningThread extends Thread
{
    private boolean _stop = false;

    /**
     * Stops the thread from listening.
     */
    private synchronized void stop()
    {
        _stop = true;
        try 
        {
            // Close the connection so the thread will return.
            _notify.close(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {          
        }          
    }

    /**
     * Listen for data from the HTTP url. After the data has been read, 
     * render the data onto the screen.
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */    
    public void run()
    {    
        StreamConnection stream = null;
        InputStream input = null;
        MDSPushInputStream pushInputStream=null;

        while (!_stop)
        {
            try 
            {    
                // Synchronize here so that we don't end up creating a connection that is never closed.
                synchronized(this)  
                {
                    // Open the connection once (or re-open after an IOException),  so we don't end up 
                    // in a race condition, where a push is lost if it comes in before the connection 
                    // is open again. We open the url with a parameter that indicates that we should 
                    // always use MDS when attempting to connect.
                    System.out.println("\n\n msg connection 1");
                    _notify = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open(URL);
                    System.out.println("\n\n msg connection 2");

                }

                while (!_stop)
                {    
                    // NOTE: the following will block until data is received.
                    System.out.println("\n\n msg notify 1");
                    stream = _notify.acceptAndOpen();
                    System.out.println("\n\n msg 1 ");

                    try 
                    {
                        System.out.println("\n\n msg 2");
                        input = stream.openInputStream();
                        System.out.println("\n\n msg 3 ");

                        pushInputStream= new MDSPushInputStream((HttpServerConnection)stream, input);

                        System.out.println("\n\n msg 4");
                        // Extract the data from the input stream.

                        DataBuffer db = new DataBuffer();

                        byte[] data = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
                        int chunk = 0;

                        while ( -1 != (chunk = input.read(data)) )
                        {
                            db.write(data, 0, chunk);
                        }

                        updateMessage(data);

                        // This method is called to accept the push.
                        pushInputStream.accept();                          

                        data = db.getArray();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e1) 
                    {
                        // A problem occurred with the input stream , however, the original 
                        // StreamConnectionNotifier is still valid.
                        //                          errorDialog(e1.toString());                   
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if ( input != null ) 
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                input.close();
                            } 
                            catch (IOException e2) 
                            {                  

                            }
                        }

                        if ( stream != null )
                        {
                            try 
                            {
                                stream.close();
                            } 
                            catch (IOException e2) 
                            {                                    
                            }
                        }                                                 
                    }
                }                  
            } 
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                // Likely the stream was closed. Catches the exception thrown by 
                // _notify.acceptAndOpen() when this program exits.
                errorDialog(ioe.toString());        
            }
            finally
            {
                /*

                if ( _notify != null ) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        _notify.close();
                        _notify = null;
                    } 
                    catch ( IOException e ) 
                    {          

                    }
                }

                 */

            }
        }
    }
}

private static void updateMessage(final byte[] data)
{
    System.out.println("\n\n msg 6");

    Application.getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            // Query the user to load the received message.

            //              Dialog.alert( new String(data));


            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    NotificationsManager.triggerImmediateEvent(ID, 0, null, null);
                    Dialog d = new Dialog( Dialog.D_OK, new String(data) ,0, null, Screen.DEFAULT_CLOSE);
                    //                      _dialogShowing = true;
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushGlobalScreen( d, 10, UiApplication.GLOBAL_MODAL );

                    // Dialog is closed at this point, so we cancel the event.                                        

                }
            } );        
        }    
    });
} 

public static void registerBpas() {

    /**
     * As the connection suffix is fixed I just use a Thread to call the connection code
     * 
     **/    
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {                   
                String registerUrl = formRegisterRequest(BPAS_URL, APP_ID, null) + ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public";
                //Dialog.alert(registerUrl);
                if ((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)
                        && RadioInfo
                                .areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN)) {
                    registerUrl += ";interface=wifi";
                }
                System.out.println("\n\n\n !!msg registerBPAS URL is:  "+ registerUrl + "\n\n");
                HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(registerUrl);
                InputStream is = httpConnection.openInputStream();
                System.out.println("\n\n\n !!!!!!!!!!!I am here ");
                String response = new String(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is));
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n msg RESPOSE CODE :    " + response);
                System.out.println("\n\n\n !!!!!!!!!!!I am here2 ");
                httpConnection.close();
                String nextUrl = formRegisterRequest(BPAS_URL, APP_ID, response) + ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public";
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n msg nextUrl :    " + nextUrl);
                System.out.println("\n\n\n !!!!!!!!!!!I am here 3");
                if ((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)
                        && RadioInfo
                                .areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN)) {
                    nextUrl += ";interface=wifi";
                    System.out.println("\n\n\n !!!!!!!!!!!I am here 4");
                }
                HttpConnection nextHttpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(nextUrl);
                InputStream nextInputStream = nextHttpConnection.openInputStream();
                response = new String(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(nextInputStream));
                System.out.println("\n\n\n !!!!!!!!!!!I am here 5");
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n msg RESPOSE CODE 1:    " + response);
                nextHttpConnection.close();
                if (REGISTER_SUCCESSFUL.equals(response) || USER_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED.equals(response)) {
                    Dialog.alert("msg Registered successfully for BIS push");

                    System.out.println("\n\n\n !!!!!!!!!!!I am here 6");
                    System.out.println("msg Registered successfully for BIS push");
                } else {
                    Dialog.alert("msg BPAS rejected registration");
                    System.out.println("msg BPAS rejected registration");
                }
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Dialog.alert("msg IOException on register() " + e + " " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("msg IOException on register() " + e + " " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public static void close(Connection conn, InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    if (os != null) {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if (is != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

public static void errorDialog(final String message)
{
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Dialog.alert(message);
        } 
    });
}

private static String formRegisterRequest(String bpasUrl, String appId, String token) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(bpasUrl);
    sb.append("/mss/PD_subReg?");
    sb.append("serviceid=").append(appId);
    sb.append("&osversion=").append(DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion());
    sb.append("&model=").append(DeviceInfo.getDeviceName());
    if (token != null && token.length() > 0) {
        sb.append("&").append(token);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

***BackGroundApplication.java***

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.ServerSocketConnection;

import net.rim.device.api.io.http.HttpServerConnection;
import net.rim.device.api.io.http.MDSPushInputStream;
import net.rim.device.api.io.http.PushInputStream;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.system.RadioInfo;
import net.rim.device.api.system.WLANInfo;

class BackgroundApplication extends Application {   

    public BackgroundApplication() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void setupBackgroundApplication(){

        MessageReadingThread messageReadingThread = new MessageReadingThread();
        messageReadingThread.start();


    }   

    private static class MessageReadingThread extends Thread {

        private boolean running;
        private ServerSocketConnection socket;
        private HttpServerConnection conn;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private PushInputStream pushInputStream;

        public MessageReadingThread() {
            this.running = true;
        }

        public void run() {

             String url = "http://:" + "33387" ;//here after the + add your port number
             url += ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public";
             if ((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) && RadioInfo.areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN)) {
                url += ";interface=wifi";
                }

            try {
                socket = (ServerSocketConnection) Connector.open( url );
            } catch( IOException ex ) {
                // can't open the port, probably taken by another application
                onListenError( ex );
            }

            while( running ) {
                try {
                    Object o = socket.acceptAndOpen();
                    conn = (HttpServerConnection) o;
                    inputStream = conn.openInputStream();
                    pushInputStream = new MDSPushInputStream( conn, inputStream );
                    PushMessageReader.process( pushInputStream, conn );
                } catch( Exception e ) {
                    if( running ) {
                      //  Logger.warn( "Failed to read push message, caused by " + e.getMessage() );
                        running = false;
                    }
                } finally {
                   // PushUtils.close( conn, pushInputStream, null );
                }
            }

          //  Logger.log( "Stopped listening for push messages" );
        }

        public void stopRunning() {
            running = false;
            //PushUtils.close( socket, null, null );
        }

        private void onListenError( final Exception ex ) {
           // Logger.warn( "Failed to open port, caused by " + ex );
          System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

On the main class , ***MyApp.java*** , as you can see everytime the application is launched, i register for push. Every time the device restarts, i start a background process to listen for push. Or at least, this is what i believe i am doing here.

Why should i do that?

I thought that by registering for push, the background listener would somehow start too... But i guess it doesn't.. That's why probably when i restart the phone, this code is executed and the push starts coming in.

How could i fix this problem so that i could start the background listener:

1. the first time the app is deployed
2. every time i restart the device
3. but NOT on every launch of the app.

Comment: @Nate could you take a look at it?

Comment: Please [take a look at this blog post I wrote](http://www.enscand.com/roller/enscand/entry/how_to_ask_for_coding).  Basically, you have included much too much information.  Please work on cleaning up your questions so they are short and well-described.  Your description of this question repeated the same information over and over again.  People helping you for free have limited time, so try hard to save them time and make your questions simple and clear.  Trust me, you'll get better answers, and everyone will be happy.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Nate for your more than welcome recommendations and editing my question for better. I didnt really mean to make my question too big. I just felt that all this code would give a full understanding of my problem. Of course all what i am describing can be seen in MyApp.java class . I added the 2 other classes just in case someone needed to see what exactly was happening under the hood. Anyway thank you a lot for trying to help, appreciate it :)